# Algorithm for forward stepwise regression

Tags: regression, cross-validation

I am trying to implement the algorithm for forward stepwise selection following the book "[Introduction to Statistical learning](https://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20First%20Printing.pdf)":

The steps listed in the book are:

```
Algorithm 6.2 Forward stepwise selection
1. Let M0 denote the null model, which contains no predictors.
2. For k = 0, . . . , p − 1:
(a) Consider all p − k models that augment the predictors in Mk
with one additional predictor.
(b) Choose the best among these p − k models, and call it Mk+1.
Here best is defined as having smallest RSS or highest R2.
3. Select a single best model from among M0, . . . ,Mp using crossvalidated
prediction error, Cp (AIC), BIC, or adjusted R2.
```

My question is I am not quite clear on whether or not cross validation should be used in step2. If so, why? or else why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> best is defined as having smallest RSS or highest R2.

Cross-validation is not mentioned here, so per the text, you would simply choose the model based on in-sample RSS or $R^2$.

Overfitting is (hopefully) controlled by the cross-validation in step 3.

Of course, nothing keeps you from modifying the algorithm given in the book. Just note that you will then do *a lot* of cross-validation, since you would cross-validate $p-k$ models in each of $p$ iterations of step 2.

Comment: If I perform cross-validation in step 2, do I still need step 3 since I can just select the model with the smallest error from step 2?

Comment: I would still do step 3. Even with cross-validation in step 2, adding another predictor may overfit. Note also that the result from step 2 is an entire *collection* of $p$ models with $0, \dots, p-1$ predictors, and step 3 consists of choosing one of these models, for which you need some criterion, and cross-validation is a good one.